# Cloudflare IP Changes do not take inmmediate effect as before

Tags: cloudflare

I'm a CloudFlare user many months ago. I love CDN cappabilities as change some domain name from one IP to a new one inmmediately with no DNS propagation issues. Well, today I tried to change some dns entries as "www" from an old IP to a new one, and change do not take the **inmmediate effect** as before. For example I changed IP one hour ago and IP is not changing yet. Always taked a few seconds to do it.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having similar issues.  According to their support status they had some issues with DNS resolution earlier today.  This could be causing some delays in updates.  I set the TTL on the record to 5 minutes to see if this will force an update.  As of now the record has not changed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope the can solve this issue asap because the main power of CDN for me is to manage IP delegation like a IP failover solution. At this moment DNS IP changes takes more than 2 hours to be effective :(

Comment: I got a confirmation that they are still working on the issue.  Looks like my records finally updated.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry about the issues (it didn't appear to affect all customers). There was an issue where information in the UI wasn't updating back to production, so customers may have seen a slight delay in getting new changes to push out (definitely not a normal situation for us).